# Can I get a reference to List<> object having a reference to one of its elements?

Tags: java, collections

For example I have a reference to an `mItem` object of my `List<mItem> mList` collection. Is that possible to get a reference to `mList` using `mItem`?

Comment: Without changing mItem's class and using a custom List implementation?

Comment: Unless you created a property on the mItem object to hold a pointer to the collection it has no way of knowing what references it. One object could be a member of multiple collections.

Comment: have a hashmap , with key as mItem and value as mList.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no.   The items in a list don't know they are in a list.  (Unless of course you add a reference to the list inside your mItem object.)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Adding an item to a list adds a reference to that object to the list. It does not affect the object itself.

You can check to see if an item is in a specific list, with `mList.contains(mItem)` which returns true if the item is in `mList`. Alternatively if you really need to, you could as others have suggested implement a version of List that informs each item that the list has a reference to that item. The overhead would be rather messy though.

Meta question: why do you need this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

As jzd said... you can add a field to your `mItem` class (for example `referenceHolder`)

```
mItem(Object ref){
    referenceHolder = ref;
}
```

class with List:

```
mList.add(new mItem(this));
```

something like that should work :) but its kind of weird ;), because normally "The items in a list don't know they are in a list. "

EDIT: and as said before - "One object should be a member of multiple collections" - so you would need to change type of my referenceHolder to some list or array, to make that able to happen.

EDIT2: that's just reference to object holding that list (if one object will have multiple lists, you wont be able to know witch of them is holding that sepecified `mItem` object), to reference to List itself you will need (as said in comment ;)) custom list implementation adding references to stored objects with `this` in `add()` method.

Comment: @Carlos oh God, so we need to store current position on list too? That would need refresing all listed items placed after removed one...

Comment: I didn't realize that @Carlos was divine ... :-)

Comment: @Stephen, if he will answer that, maybe he truly is.. ;) anyway, I missed comma <ashamed> :)

Comment: so I prefer not to answer it... [:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a container for all you lists, you can call `contains` on each one to find which list the item is in.

Note: for a list you can have the same element multiple time, and across multiple list.

BTW: If you don't want duplicates in a list and don't care about the order of elements then a Set may be your best choice.